# Intel 8008 stack behavior

Tags: intel, microprocessor, 8008

Intel 8008 CPU has an internal stack, implemented as an 8 x 14-bit scratchpad. How does it work exactly? Is there any "invisible 3-bit stack pointer"?

I want to know what happens when the stack is full and call operation is performed. Is the stack "infinite" and the oldest value is dropped, or the oldest saved return address is overwritten?

And what happens when the stack is "empty" and return operation is performed? Does it read any undefined/unpredictable value?

Comment: Interest only: A friend did a Masters degree using an 8008 and (AFAIR) 1702 EPROMS. About 1974 from memory. I'll send hin a link to this thread for interest :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Intel 8008 CPU has an internal stack, implemented as an 8 x 16-bit scratchpad.

No, it's entries are 'only' 14 bit long, as all addressing on the 8008 supports only 14 bit (*1).

> How does it work exactly? Is there any "invisible 3-bit stack pointer"?

Yes. In reality it's not  a stack pointer, but selects the active PC.

```
A three-bit address pointer is used to designate the present
location of the program counter.
```

(From the 1973 User Manual section III.B.1 p.7)

> I want to know what happens when the stack is full and call operation is performed.

It simply cycles (7->0).

```
When the capacity of the stack is exceeded, the address pointer
recycles and the content of the lowest level register is destroyed.
```

(From the 1973 User Manual section III.B.1 p.7)

> Is the stack "infinite" and the oldest value is dropped, or the oldest saved return address is overwritten?

Erm, not clear what 'dropping' is supposed meant. The stack pointer simply runs over, reusing the oldest entry (see above)

> And what happens when the stack is "empty" and return operation is performed? Does it read any undefined/unpredictable value?

It switches to the previous PC, which my hold an undefined value - or to be exact, whatever has been left here by some previous use.

The manual states that all registers, as well as stack pointer and stack are cleared (*2) on startup (*3).

```
When power (Voo ) and clocks (cP1 , cP2 ) are first turned on, a flip-flop internal to the
8008 is set by sensing the rise of Voo . This internal signal forces a HALT (00000000)
into the instruction register and the 8008 is then in the STOPPED state. The following
sixteen clock periods after entering the STOPPED state are required to clear (logic "0")
memories (accumulator, scratch pad, program counter, and stack). During this time the
interrupt line has been at logic "0". Any ti me after the memories are cleared, the 8008
is ready for normal operation.
```

(From the 1973 User Manual section V.A.2 p.20)

---

*1 - The top two bits of the second address byte signal the access type as

- Program
- Memory Read
- IO
- Memory Write

*2 - Personally I'd be a bit careful here, as 16 cycles do not really seam enough to do all of this.

*3 - The 8008 has no Reset input, but uses power-up to initialize.

Comment: (My mistake, of course, there are 14 bit long... Thank you)

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. So: the processor would be using "register N" as program counter... a call instruction would increment the "stack pointer" thus switching to a new PC, store the call target address in "register N+1", and carry on executing?  Do I have that right?  (Not necessarily the exact micro-sequence, just the general idea)

Comment: @another-dave Thats the idea how I understand it. It's the great advantage of having an on chip stack. CALL becomes as fast as JMP.

Comment: So, what prevents the stack from overflowing? Does the compiler (or the programmer writing 8008 assembly) constantly have to keep track of how many call levels they have used up (which would somewhat limit its usefulness, e. g. in regards to recursion)?

Comment: @Taschi IIUIC the stack is implemented as a ring buffer.  The first 8 (nested) calls get slots 0 through 7; if there's a 9th nested call it overwrites the value in slot 0 (likewise a 10th nested call overwrites the value in slot 1, etc.).

Comment: @AlexHajnal, yes, I understand that. My question is, how is accidental data loss avoided?

Comment: @Taschi I don't think it is.

Comment: @Taschi Nothing. Come on, who needs more than 7 subroutine level? I'm smiling while being serious. We talk about one of the first CPUs, barely functional. There is no room to add hardware to pamper bad programming. Just think about the additional requirements beside checking, like issueing exception and handling them. That didn't become a thing in common micros until a decade later. Literally no room  for such runtime issues as well, as 1 KiB semiconductor memory in 1973 was about 800-1000 USD. Last but not least, it's never accidental how many levels a program uses.

Comment: @Raffzahn, my main concern / thought here is recursion, which I would not necessarily call "bad programming". I'm aware that the 8008 was very early and very simple, I'm just curious how people dealt with the restrictions back then. Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: @Taschi for one, recursion is a rather exotic technique in real world programming. Great for teaching, but almost no real world use case. More important here is that the 8008 is mainly use for fixed programming (embedded). There is even less use for that. And last but not least, the 8008 is due being so early an outlier for 8 bit as well. Then again no other 8 bit CPU had stack checking. In fact, it wasn't until the 386 that stack underflow was checked at all. So the issue wasn't one until way later.

Comment: *Great for teaching, but almost no real world use case.*  I take it you've never needed to parse JSON?

Comment: @another-dave <old fat voice>Is that what they teach the kids this days?</> Serious, JSON is no different from XML, or any of these explicite structured formats. Used them a lot already before it was a thing (Yes, we did write complex hierarchical data structures on tape). Data comes in serial and is processed as such (remember SAX?), end ends up in serial memory (as records). I can't see the need to waste resources in going recursive, when all that's needed is a few markers to keep track. Not back then and not today.

Comment: @another-dave The be fair, I professionally **did** use recursion - exactly once. In a program to fix up a linkage structure in an offline situation where time doesn't matter. Then again, it was not only a perfect use case, but also meant as a show off to my colleagues. So yeah, one use case in 40 years real world programming in various environments from mainframe to micro from large scale ERP to embedded.

Comment: "O, thou hast damnable iteration, and art indeed able to corrupt a saint."  - Falstaff, in *Henry IV, part 1*, act 1 scene 2.

Comment: @Taschi Oh, and one more thing to keep in mind: Recursion only works if there's as well a parameter/data stack. The 8008 on chip stack is a strict return stack. there are no instruction to store data or to manipulate it in any way but call/return.